# Как сделать проверку на цифры в функции вичесления факториала числа который ввёл пользователь

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы, рекурсия, факториал

После ввода данных добавить проверку их корректности. Если пользователь не ввел число, либо при вводе указал не число, - спросить число заново (при этом значением по умолчанию для него должна быть введенная ранее информация).

```
    'let factorialNum = +prompt('Enter num for factorial');
while (Number.isNaN(factorialNum)) {
    let againFactorialNum = +prompt('Enter num for factorial again, use only numbers');
    if (Number.isNaN(againFactorialNum)) {
        againFactorialNum;
    }else if (!Number.isNaN(againFactorialNum)){
        break;
    }
    alert( factorial(factorialNum) );
}
function factorial(n) {
    return (n !== 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) :1;
}
alert( factorial(factorialNum) );'
```

Comment: Кстати, юзер существо творческое, и может ввести два с половиной...

Comment: Вопрос в том чтобы когда пользователь ввёл не число та запросило заново, оно запрашивает но когда я ввожу число, дальше оно не работает и не выводит в alert факториал числа которое было введённое в цикл и в консоле выдеает ошибку в рекурсии и в debugger то же самое

Comment: как решить эту ошибку

Comment: Ну так задайте его В ТЕКСТЕ.

Comment: кого? и в каком??

Comment: Под текстом вопроса есть ссылка "править". Вот её и нажмите...

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо вызывать функцию для введенного числа - againFactorialNum

```
 alert( factorial(againFactorialNum));
```